# How Can we configure OAuth 2 to work only for a particular email id?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, microservices, spring-security-oauth2

Suppose I have an application in which I have enabled (google) `Oauth2` authentication but  I want only a few business people can log in to my application with there specific email id and rest of the people can't. How Can we achieve this using Oauth2?

1.) Lots of people have a Google account and can authenticate with Google

2.) I want Only some of them should be authorized to use your app, which maybe deals with business assets

Comment: What do you mean by "people can login to my application"?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your requirement is:

- Lots of people have a Google account and can authenticate with Google
- Only some of them should be authorized to use your app, which maybe deals with corporate assets

In this case I would proceed something like this:

**STEP 1: PREREQUISITE USER SETUP**

Get a list of users and perform an Administrator Approval step to create them in your product database, perhaps with **Name** and **Email** fields.

**STEP 2: INCLUDE THE EMAIL SCOPE DURING LOGINS**

In the Google login redirect, use **scope='openid email'** so that you can identify the user via email after login. Allow users to successfully authenticate.

**STEP 3: AFTER LOGIN PROCESS THE ACCESS TOKEN**

You will then get then be able to get the user's email address from the access token (though you may have to send it to the Google User Info endpoint).

**STEP 4: DENY ACCESS WHEN REQUIRED**

If you can't find the email associated to the token in your product user data, present a Forbidden message to the user.

**FURTHER INFO**

See my [User Data Write Up](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/02/user-data) for further details on technical options. Note that I have not actually tested this with Google, but I have used the general approach with a few different systems.

Comment: Yes I have some list of users  only they should be allowed to use the app what should I need to do .how can we restrict other users from using the app

Comment: OK - have updated my original answer with further detais.